# Packaging Dependent JARs into apklib with Maven

Tags: android, maven, maven-assembly-plugin, android-maven-plugin, apklib

I am developing an Android class library that compiles to an apklib using Maven.  However, when I build the library project (mvn clean install), my dependent JARs (of which there are about 12) are not included in the apklib.   I know that the Assembly plugin can be used to accomplish this but am not sure what the appropriate steps are to be able to package an apklib with dependent JARs.

Comment: Could you show your pom file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The apklib format should NOT include the dependencies. They are just declared in its pom.

When you then use the apklib in an actual application and add a dependency to it in your pom, the Android Maven Plugin will include the apklib as well as all its dependencies into your application.